Is it possible to remove a physical disk from a storage pool on Windows 11?
I have a storage pool on my Windows 11 system that is configured like this.

I want to remove one of the physical disks from this pool.
From the UI, it seems I can only Extend the pool size.
From Powershell, I tried resize-virtualdisk -FriendlyName "TieredDisk" -Size (607GB), but got this error:
resize-virtualdisk : Not Supported

Extended information:
The Windows Storage Provider does not support shrinking virtual disks.

I wonder if I forgot to install some system tools. If MS does not support resizing a virtual disk, why do they provide this command?

Apparently "Note: The ability to expand or shrink is vendor specific." -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/resize-virtualdisk?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Yeah...but I am using the Windows storage provider.

you can only take down the entire storage due you ran just a raid 0 if i read correctly. and the button is in the screenshot
